# Handle Failure Of Updating displayName in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

as far as I know, there is no option to set displayName with email and password when signing up a user using firebase auth.

for example, if I have a signup form like this

[image]

I can handle the profile update just after the createUserWithEmailAndPassword has succeeded.
or I can create an onboarding section where I could just ask the user separately for their name, and remove the name from this form. which is what I'm currently doing.

but when asking for the name in the form itself what if the signup has succeeded but the display name update has failed. what am I supposed to do in that situation

Comment: What is the code for this operation?

Comment: *what am I supposed to do in that situation*? Tell the user the displayName failed and ask them to try again? Just like if they are signing up with an email that's already in use - you notify the user it's already in use and ask for another. Not sure what the question actually is here - can you clarify?

Comment: did you ever found an error saying your name update failed? the moment the signup is successful the user is signed in. and the route updates are triggered. and moreover its bad UX.

Comment: lol. I didn't literally mean 'failed'. I meant present an error to the user 'The Display Name is in use, try again' or 'The Display Name can only contain the characters A-Z'. The moment the signup is succssful the user may be signed in, but that doesn't mean anything. A simple rule would ensure that have a valid display name before they can access any data. Also, if they decide not to proceed and hit Cancel, you can just delete that user. By the way, if you are replying to another user, be sure to precede it with an at symbol  before their name, like @akashmohan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to define the course of action on your own, depending on the requirements of your app.  There is not a single correct way to handle this.

You could send the user to another form that asks them for their profile information again, or you could simply ignore the error and let them update profile information later.  It's entirely up to you.